# Wampserver - Acessando o cmd.exe do windows e executando um arquivo .bat

Tags: wamp

Bom dia pessoal,

Assim como dito no título, preciso acessar o cmd.exe do windows através do Wampservere e executar um arquivo .bat.
Fiz o seguinte cód. php para executar o descrito acima:

```
<?php
$batname = "chamaCalc.bat" ; 
$output = shell_exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c $batname"); 

echo $output; 
?>
```

Obtive sucesso com a minha necessidade no Xampp, mas no Wampserve, nada acontece.
Alguém sabe se tem alguma forma disso funcionar no wamp?

Obrigada!

Answer (score -1):

O problema deve ser o safe-mode que está ativo

A solução é:

interrompa todos os serviços do Wamp-Server e feche o programa

Abra ... / wamp / bin / apache / Apache2 ../ bin / php.ini Copie php.ini para desktop e

defina safe_mode_exec_dir (linha após = está vazia, então está on) ponha em Off!

Salve

Copiar de volta para dir (talvez você precise de direitos de administrador) reiniciar o wamp-server

EDIT

Outra solução seria tentar usar a função `system();`

Comment: Faz diferença onde a linha " safe_mode_exec_dir = off " é definida dentro do php.ini? Eu defini esse parâmetro na ultima linha do arquivo mas não funcionou. :(

Comment: Então normalmente essa linha já existe, não é preciso adicionar

Comment: Essa linha não existia no meu php.ini =(

Comment: eu sei que tambem existe uma opcao no icon na barra de tarefas que ativa ou desativa as interacoes com o host, deixa me informar mais um pouco pois ja nao tenho wamp instalado

Comment: Entao outras coisas a verificar seriam

Wamp a correr como administrador

Se alteras-te a php.ini do apache2 e nao a que esta na pasta php

Parar os servicos e reiniciar o wamp completamente
Verificar tambem se no ficheiro php nao tem uma linha 'disable_functions' com essas funcoes marcadas

eu tentei aqui do meu lado e funcionou depois de ter adicionado 'safe_mode_exec_dir = off'

Comment: Tentei tudo o que você falou, mas não funciona. O php do meu wampserver é o 7.2.18. Não sei se isso pode influenciar em algo.